# SELinux and chroot system call

Tags: root, chroot, selinux

*TL; DR: This is a question about the final step, in a portable, developer-oriented rooting process, that works across all Android machines. It is not based on any exploit - it is something that we are legally and morally allowed to do, as developers, to our own machines. If I get an answer and manage to chroot inside my Debian, I will make a concise blog post detailing all the steps of this process for all the fellow developers that want root access to their tablets - and don't want to trust dubious-origin "one-click-roots" that do God-knows-what to their machines (botnet members?)...  The only dependencies will be the machine's kernel sources (which the manufacturer is legally obligated to provide) and the boot partition image (`boot.img`), which is 99% of the times inside the manufacturer-provided Over-the-air updates, or individually downloadable as a standalone flash-able image.*

So, a week passed where I spent all my free time on my new Android tablet.

And I have almost completely succeeded - in creating a portable, developer-oriented process, for achieving root in my Android 5.0.2 tablet.

But there's one thing missing yet - I can't do a chroot (which I need to run my `debootstrap`-ed Debian!)

**What I did so far**

1. First, I did a minor patch in my tablet's (manufacturer-provided) kernel sources, and then compiled my own kernel - where I disabled the checks for changing *SELINUX enforcing mode*. Specifically...

In `security/selinux/selinuxfs.c`:

```
...
if (new_value != selinux_enforcing) {
    /* Commented out by ttsiodras.
    length = task_has_security(current, SECURITY__SETENFORCE);
    if (length)
        goto out;
    */
    audit_log(current->audit_context, GFP_KERNEL, AUDIT_MAC_STATUS,
        "enforcing=%d old_enforcing=%d auid=%u ses=%u",
        new_value, selinux_enforcing,
```

2. I then changed my initrd image's `/default.prop` to contain: `ro.secure=0` and `ro.debuggable=1`
3. Since my manufacturer's `initrd.img` was missing it, I also compiled `su.c` from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/ and placed the resulting binary under `/sbin`, making sure it is set to SUID root (`chmod 04755 /sbin/su`).

After that, I packaged the new kernel and the new initrd, as I explained [in Episode 2 of my previous post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124344/trying-to-flash-a-system-img-i-took-with-dd-failing) - and booted from my own image:

```
adb reboot boot-loader ; fastboot boot myboot.img
```

**So, are you root?**

Yes, it initially appeared to be successful:

```
$ adb shell

shell@K01E_2:/ $ id

uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),
1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),
3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) 
context=u:r:shell:s0

shell@K01E_2:/ $ ls -l /sbin/su /sbin/_su
-rwxr-xr-x root     root          131 2015-10-03 10:44 su
-rwsr-xr-x root     root         9420 2015-10-03 01:31 _su

(the _su is the binary I compiled, set to SUID root, and "su" is
 a script I wrote to tell "su" to add me to all these groups...)

shell@K01E_2:/ $ cat /sbin/su

#!/system/bin/sh
export PATH=/system/bin:$PATH
exec /sbin/_su 0,0,1000,1028,2000,2001,1004,1007,1011,1015,\
   1028,3001,3002,3003,3006
```

And I have now achieved root:

```
shell@K01E_2:/ $ su

root@K01E_2:/ # id

uid=0(root) gid=0(root) 
groups=1000(system),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),
1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),1028(sdcard_r),2000(shell),2001(cache),
3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) 
context=u:r:shell:s0
```

I am 100% sure I am root - not only because `id` says so, but because I can also do things that normal processes definitely can't:

```
root@K01E_2:/ # ls -l /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/boot
lrwxrwxrwx root root 2015-10-03 10:47 boot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16

root@K01E_2:/ # dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p16 of=/dev/null bs=1M
16+0 records in
16+0 records out
16777216 bytes transferred in 0.569 secs (29485441 bytes/sec)
```

Lo and behold - I can finally read raw partitions out of my tablet!

And SELinux is indeed in "down, dog" mode:

```
root@K01E_2:/ # getenforce                                                     
Permissive
```

But... there are *still* things I can't do:

```
root@K01E_2:/ # mkdir /my_mnt

root@K01E_2:/ # mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /my_mnt
mount: Operation not permitted
```

That is, I can't mount my EXT4-fs formatted 2nd partition of my external SD card.

I also can't chroot to my lovely `debootstrap`-ed Debian:

```
root@K01E_2:/ # chroot /data/debian/ /bin/bash                             
chroot() fail
Operation not permitted
```

**Is it because of SELinux?**

I don't know - I am new (very new - one week old) to SELinux. I thought that when you put it to sleep (`getenforce` reporting "Permissive") it no longer interferes...

Apparently, I was wrong. Down the rabbit hole we go again...

Could it be because of my process context?

Remember that `id` returned... "uid=0(root) gid=0(root)... **context=u:r:shell:s0**"

Can I change that context? Being root and all, can I move away from `shell`? And if so, move to what?

The answer to the first question is `runcon`:

```
shell@K01E_2:/ $ runcon u:r:debuggerd:s0 /sbin/su

root@K01E_2:/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)... context=u:r:debuggerd:s0
```

Good. But what context will allow me to `mount` and `chroot`?

Reading some more about SELinux, back in my main machine, I parse the `/sepolicy` file on the root of the `initrd.img`:

```
linuxbox$ $ sesearch -A sepolicy | grep chroot
allow init_shell init_shell : capability { chown sys_chroot ...
allow init init : capability { chown dac_read_search sys_chroot ...
allow kernel kernel : capability { chown dac_override sys_chroot ... 
allow asus-dbug-d asus-dbug-d : capability { chown sys_chroot ...
...
```

OK, a number of possibilities! Especially that `kernel` one seems promising:

```
shell@K01E_2:/ $ runcon u:r:kernel:s0 /sbin/su

root@K01E_2:/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)... context=u:r:kernel:s0

root@K01E_2:/ # chroot /data/debian/ /bin/bash                             
chroot() fail
Operation not permitted
```

Darn.

Who the heck is blocking me from `chroot`ing?

Any advice most welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Who the heck is blocking me from chrooting?*

It wasn't SELinux - that was a wild goose chase (`getenforce` returning "Permissive" means that SELinux is indeed no longer in the picture).

The culprit - after adding quite a number of `printk` in the kernel's source to trace the failures of both `chroot` and `mount` - turned out to be *capabilities*. More specifically, Android's "capability bounding set" - you can read all about them via your `man` (`man 7 capabilities`) and I confess I have never before bothered looking into them - my everyday UNIX tasks depended on them and I had no idea...  try this in your linux box to see for yourself:

```
$ getfattr -d -m - /sbin/ping
getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: sbin/ping
security.capability=0s......
```

See? Ping is no longer SUID root - it uses information **stored in the filesystem's extended attributes** to know that it has access to the raw sockets layer (so it can do it's ICMP thing - at the IP level that is).

Anyway, I digress - the surgery point in my kernel where I stopped the "drop my capabilities set" - in an arguably disgusting, "let them all march in" manner - was this (`security/commoncap.c`):

```
static long cap_prctl_drop(struct cred *new, unsigned long cap)
{
    if (!capable(CAP_SETPCAP))
        return -EPERM;
    if (!cap_valid(cap))
        return -EINVAL;

    // ttsiodras: come in, everyone, the water's fine!
    //cap_lower(new->cap_bset, cap);
    return 0;
}
```

This means that capabilities are NEVER dropped - a very secure configuration, indeed :-)

```
$ adb shell

shell@K01E_2:/ $ su

root@K01E_2:/ # chroot /data/debian/ /bin/bash

root@localhost:/# export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:\
     /usr/local/bin:$PATH

root@localhost:/# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l
```

Hello, my sweet Debian :-)

Oh, and "Root checker" works, too - I snipped "su.c", so everyone in my tablet can become root:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct passwd *pw;
  uid_t uid, myuid;
  gid_t gid, gids[50];

  /* Until we have something better, only root and shell can use su. */
  myuid = getuid();
  //
  // ttsiodras - Oh no, you don't :-)
  //
  //if (myuid != AID_ROOT && myuid != AID_SHELL) {
  //    fprintf(stderr,"su: uid %d not allowed to su\n", myuid);
  //    return 1;
  //}
```

Now that it works, I must make it work properly - i.e. allow only my `termux` and `Terminal Emulator` users to invoke `su` and `chroot`, and not let everyone and their grandmother in :-)